# Como faço para inserir uma imagem como background de uma div?

Tags: html, css, imagem, background

quero adicionar uma imagem como background de uma div, e para isto, estou utilizando o seguinte código:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <div class="imagemDeFundo">
                <p>Hello world</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

No meu CSS está assim:

```
.imagemDeFundo{
    background-image: url(imgs/backgroundpage.png); 
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
}
```

Minha imagem não está aparecendo. O que estou fazendo de errado?

Comment: Provavelmente o caminho para o arquivo de imagem. Lembre que ele é relativo à localização do arquivo .CSS e não do .HTML.

Comment: o caminho da sua foto esta certo ?

Answer (score 3):

Aparentemente está tudo correto. Tente usar  `background`, ao invés de  `background-image`:

```
.imagemDeFundo{
    background: url('imgs/backgroundpage.png'); 
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
}
```

Comment: Usar aspas na `url()` é opcional.

Comment: Na verdade o / em seu caminho, significa voltar a pasta raíz do projeto. existem a denotação `..` que sobe um nível de pasta e a denotação `/` que volta para a pasta raíz. então com esta barra você ja está alterando totalmente o caminho da imagem, caso a pasta imgs esteja no mesmo diretório que o arquivo css em que ele está chamando, este `/` iria fazer a imagem não ser encontrada a menos que ambas estejam na pasta raíz que será enxergada.

Comment: @AldoFernandesJunior, obrigada pela explicação. Realmente, eu não sei onde está a imagem dele, não posso afirmar que deve colocar a "/". Editei minha resposta.

Answer (score 1):

Parece estar funcionando....Verifique o path, como mencionado no comentário.

```css
.imagemDeFundo{
    border: 1px solid black;
    background: url('https://www.askideas.com/media/11/Evolution-Something-Went-Wrong-Funny-Computer.jpg') no-repeat; 
    width: auto;
    height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <div class="imagemDeFundo">
                <p>Hello world</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: A imagem ainda não aparece :/

Comment: coloca o restante do css....

Answer (score 0):

Cristian, provavelmente é o nível da sua pasta, tente uma das opções abaixo:

```
background-image: url("./imgs/backgroundpage.png"); 
background-image: url("../imgs/backgroundpage.png"); 
background-image: url(".../imgs/backgroundpage.png");
```

Answer (score -2):

se você usou boas práticas e criou uma pasta para as folhas de estilo e uma pasta para os assets, vai precisar usar uma ' / ' antes do src que deseja encontrar.

ex:

(pasta assets) contem a imagem que deseja aplicar como fundo.
(pasta styles) contem seu arquivo css

logo você usará o seguinte código :

```css
.imagemDeFundo{
    background-image: url(/assets/backgroundpage.png); 
{
```

e para a imagem tomar todo o espaço da div, basta criar outra class 'container' na mesma div e usar:

```css
.container{
    height: 100vh;
    background-size: contain;
}
```

Espero ter ajudado :)